# How to create customize LSTM Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a model like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(100, 5, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
```

I was surfing on the internet for enhance the layer like this on below:

1. Input Layer - 7 feature
2. Recurrent Layer - 8 hidden unit
3. Fully Connected Layer - 4 neuron
4. Output Layer - 2 neuron

Here's my code I've been tried

```html
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(feature, input_shape = input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

But I didn't find anything - how to enhance layer like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried so far? It makes it easier to help you where you struggle, if we have something to work with. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to have an idea what is needed to get answers to help you.

Comment: @marcelh Yes, im sorry i can't upload the image and now, i update it on the question. Thanks for the feedback and your advice